# Redux saga pass multiple parameter as action and get it into saga function React native

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-saga

i want to pass multiple parameters in Redux saga action so i did code as below

```
this.props.addCartData(_addToCartObject, 'guest')
```

inside dispatch i am passing like below

```
addCartData: (value, isFor) => dispatch(addCartRequest(value, isFor)),
```

in saga function I am accessing as below

```
function* callAddCart(data, isFor) {
  try {
      console.log("isFor--->", isFor);
     }
   }

export function* cartSaga() {
return yield all([
    yield takeLatest(actionTypes.ADD_CART_REQUEST, callAddCart),
]);
```

}

But i log isFor I got undefined can you help me what i making wrong on this ?

Comment: did you print data. Is it also undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it all works around your action creator `addCartRequest`,

let's say it returns an object like:

```js
function addCartRequest(value, isFor) {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.ADD_CART_REQUEST,
    value,
    isFor
  };
}
```

your saga watcher `yield takeLatest(actionTypes.ADD_CART_REQUEST, callAddCart)`, will pass the whole object to `callAddCart`,

you can access their values assuming the first param as the whole object:

```js
function callAddCart(action) {
  console.log("actionType--->", action.type);
  console.log("value--->", action.value);
  console.log("isFor--->", action.isFor);
}
```

i created a working example in CodeSandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/2021-03-25-redux-saga-action-creator-payload-hk4sb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I tried something similar on my project, but the action seems dispatched automatically